# How to start a new program from service(daemon)?

Tags: python, security, services

I am writing a simple python script that run as daemon on Ubuntu. I've successfully installed and started it by writing a valid init.d startup script.

The question is, can I(and how can I) invoke another program from that daemon process?

I've tried:

```
os.system("/bin/cp /tmp/somefileA /tmp/somefileB")
subprocess.call(["/bin/cp", "/tmp/somefileA", "/tmp/somefileB"])
# i'am not actually copying files, here i use cp for illustration because it doesn't involve stdin/stdout.
```

but both of them don't work(`os.system` is returning `256` and `subprocess.call` is returning `1`) when the script is started by:

```
sudo service some_service start
```

But if I execute the script from terminal, it works well. Is this caused by some security policy? Thanks.

Comment: 1.) What version of ubuntu are you using? I think ubuntu uses `systemd` since 15.04 (?) and as I am probably a "youngster" I don't have much knowledge of `init.d` scripts. 2.) Why are you using a python script if you are just going to call bash commands from it? 3.) What is the status of the service file? 4.) Post the actual scripts not silly "examples" that you think are relevant.

Comment: @j-money 1) i’m on 16.04. 2)I am not calling bash commands from python, It’s for listening tcp connections and when a magic packet arrives, return something generated by external program. 3)it is located in `/etc/init.d` and registered with `update-rc.d some_service defaults` the service starts fine because i can get response from tcp connection.

Comment: You've missed the most important I asked, actually post the file not some stupid example that is *similar* to yours, it's useless noise in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use init scripts. In /etc/init/
example.conf

```
    description     "My app"

start on startup
stop on shutdown
respawn
respawn limit 60 10

exec sudo blablabla
```